# Java Scanner Input Loop

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I've got a loop that is controlled by a variable called `running` which tells if the program is running or not. I am trying to achieve a loop that the user enters a command, and the program is answering him, but for some reason, It's seems like my String splits if its more than one word, this is what I have tried:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ScannerTest{
    private boolean running = true;
    public ScannerTest(){
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        while(running){
           String command = s.next();
           System.out.println(command);
        }
    }
}
```

If I am entering two or more words in the Scanner, It seems to split them.

```
Input  >> Hello what's your name?
Output >> Hello
       >> what's
       >> your
       >> name?
```

Maybe it's because of the While loop? How can i fix it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Scanner#next()` does just this -- it grabs the next token defined by any white-space delimiter(s), and does not get the next line. If your words have white space between them, it will grab the individual words one at a time with each invocation of the method.

Use `Scanner#nextLine()` instead if you want to grab the complete line that the user entered.

Edit: this question has to be a duplicate of another somewhere on this site.

Answer (score 0):

[next()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29) method will split your input by space delimiter.

[nextLine()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29) method will fix your problem. nextLine(); will read the entire line at once.

Replace `String command = s.next();` to   `String command = s.nextLine();`

Comment: But how does this work if you need to get integer inputs in a loop? I noticed that nextInt seems to skip an input because of a RETURN character (I presume).

Answer (score 0):

You're using

```
System.out.println();
```

just use

```
System.out.print();
```

only use println if you want the next output/input to be entered onto the next line.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `end-of-file indicator`, the loop you used in your solution is called `sentinel-controlled repetition` the I think the better value to control it is by using `end-of-file indicator` take look at my answer [java Scanner.hasNext() usage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42130999/4251431)