# Unable to print array after taking user input

Tags: java

I'm missing something  in accepting input from keyboard and store it in array.

This is what I tried:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");

        Scanner obj=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter sentence ");
        String[] inputArray = new String[10];
        int i = 0;
        while (obj.hasNext()){
           String word = (String) obj.next();
           inputArray[i] = word;
           System.out.println("word is  " + word);
           System.out.println("array is  " + inputArray[i]);

        }
        System.out.println("final array is  " + inputArray); //This line doesn't print. Why ?
     }
```

Why I can't print the array after while loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because you are already incrementing `i`

change to

```
String word = (String) obj.next();
inputArray[i] = word;
System.out.println("word is  " + word);
System.out.println("array is  " + inputArray[i]);
// now increment
i++;
```

The reason that the last line is not printing is that the `obj.hasNext` is blocking waiting for input, you need somehow to break, also see [java Scanner.hasNext() usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21641083/java-scanner-hasnext-usage/42130999#42130999)

Comment: that so stupid. Thank but I'm stuck at one more thing. Can you tell me why the last print statement after while loop isnt executing?

Comment: the `obj.hasNext` is blocking waiting for input,  you need somehow to break, also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/42130999/2310289 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42381990/breaking-out-of-scanner-hasnext-loop

Comment: please add the link to your answer. I'll accept it. Thanks for your time. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for cycle.

would be something like:

```
for(int I; i<inputArray.length;i ++){
System.out.println("word is  " + word);
System.out.println("array is  " + inputArray[i]);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

variable "i" is being incremented at wrong place so `System.out.println("array is  " + inputArray[I])` doesn't print any value.

Statement `System.out.println("final array is  " + inputArray)` is not reached because while loop is never exited. Please see below code, I exited while loop after 10 entries and it would print the final array.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");

        Scanner obj=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter sentence ");
        String[] inputArray = new String[10];
        int i = 0;
        while (obj.hasNext()){
            if(i >= 10){
                break;
            }
            String word = (String) obj.next();
            inputArray[i] = word;
            System.out.println("word is  " + word);
            System.out.println("array is  " + inputArray[i]);
            i++; //pls ignore this dumb error

        }
        System.out.println("final array is  " + inputArray); //This line doesn't print. Why ?
        Arrays.stream(inputArray).forEach(System.out::println);
    }
```